# how to get album image in from fb in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

```
NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/100002944043966/albums?access_token=[your access token]"]; 

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
NSLog(@"%@",data);
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

by using this i am able to get the json data,but how to get image from this,help me out!thanks in advance!

Comment: Post that Json to see how it looks like..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get cover photo use this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<id>/picture?type=album&access_token=<token>
```

here id is cover_photo in the json that you received and access token is your session token.

Comment: how to fetch image data from url1,my question is this only!

Comment: Parse json from url1's response, you said you are getting json, from there you will find array of album details, take cover_photo for desired album and then use this url to fetch image data.

Comment: i have accessed the cover_photo properly,but when i m getting the data at url:https://graph.facebook.com/<album id>/photos,for getting the photos    it returns       {"data":[]}

Comment: definitely yes with 114750591966408

Answer (score 1):

You have failed to allocate memory for the incoming `imagedata(NSData alloc)`.

you can use this code ...

```
NSString *imageurl;
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]];

UIImageView *imageview;
imageview.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: how to fetch image data from url1,my question is this only!